# Condition check for null does not work with functions

Tags: typescript

Hypothetically, if I have the following function:

```js
function nullOrString(): string | null {
  return null;
}
```

This this does not produce any errors:

```js
const value = nullOrString();
if (value) {
  const foo: string = value;
}
```

But the following does produce the error `Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.`:

```js
if (nullOrString()) {
  const foo: string = nullOrString();
}
```

Am I misunderstanding something about functions, or is this a TypeScript error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a TypeScript error. In general, there's no guarantee that the same function will return the same value (or a value of the same subtype of a union type) in different invocations, even if the function has no parameters. So TypeScript won't assume that.

Regarding your code, the fact that the first call returns a truthy value says nothing about the value returned by the second call. Each new call is a new value for TypeScript.

Comment: Ahh, of course.  I completely missed that.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

As your functions return string|null you just need to write:

```
if (nullOrString()) {
    const foo: string | null = nullOrString();
}
```

as nullOrString() may return null, it is not assignable to string in strict mode in typescript.